# What's the difference between running job and enabled job

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, job-scheduling

Is there any  difference between running job and enabled job ?

Answer (score 1):

The job with the `Enabled` status will be picked up by the job coordinator for processing. Any newly created job is disabled by default, so you must enable it before it can run. When a job is enabled, a validity check is performed. If the check fails, the job is not enabled.

If you enable a disabled job, it begins to run immediately according to its schedule.

A running job is an enabled job that perform any of its task at the time.

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034) to explore more